# Material UI TextField outlined not rendering correctly

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, textfield

I am trying to add a TextField with outline in my project but it does not render correctly.

I get the following

[image]

I have no idea why, if run it in CodePen it works just fine.

Any idea why I get the underline of the text area showing up and also shifting the content so that it is not centered inside the outline border?

Component:

```
import React from 'react';

import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';


class Test extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <TextField
                label="some text"
                margin="normal"
                variant="outlined"
            />
        );
    }
}


export default Test;
```

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the element in the browser to see if there's another element rendering above or beneath?

Comment: Please check if there are any external styles that can potentially override or just interfere with the ones that are from material ui. Almost every time I had the similar problem before it turned out that there were extra styles. Styles may come from other libraries you might use, e.g. bootstrap.

Comment: If you are using Material UI 1.5 or lower, the variant prop is not available.